# Like the Higgs sector of the standard model, is there a SUSY sector which is also such a sector?

Tags: supersymmetry, dark-matter, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

This question arose from an application of the virial theorem that showed how Bose-Einstein condensates of astrophysical dimension could arise from condensing clouds of normal phase bosons. If these clouds consisted of the reservoirs of suspected dark matter at the super-cluster size scale, and a boson gas is the origin of the dark matter, then the boson mass would be about 1 ev.

Since this would be the mass of the super-symmetric boson partner of a neutrino, it seems that dark matter would be a BE condensate consisting of sneutrinos. However, given the mass of objections that can be raised against any proposal of the standard flavor sneutrinos, it seemed that the sterile particles would fit the bill.

But since the sterile sneutrino would be much heavier than its partner due to the SUSY breaking needed to explain the failure to detect super-symmetric partners of the known particles at the LHC, it does not provide a viable candidate.

There is, however, an almost obvious solution to this problem--one that would, for a Wess-Zumino model, imply that there are only four super-symmetric particles and that the putative SUSY partners of the familiar particles simply don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to argue that the super-symmetric fields are fundamental quantum fields in their own right, that, like the Higgs field, comprise a sector of the Standard model.

Since the coupling constant, the super-symmetric charge, appearing in an interacting WZ model would be a fundamental constant it could not be the charge on an electron or color charge on a quark.

This means that the rest of the interactions could not be invariant under super-symmetry or their SUSY couplings would be the electric charge, color charge, etc.

If so, a W-Z multiplet consisting of only four particles, which is certainly appropriate to a fundamental interaction, would comprise the full list of super-symmetric particles.

If it is assumed these particle have zero weak charge, zero color charge; and zero electric charge, then the only coupling to the other sectors would be with gravity.

As an extension of this scheme, suppose that the Higgs and SUSY sectors couple to each other, but no others. If the interaction is analogous to QED, this would introduce a new fundamental coupling parameter as the analogous charge e*.

It then becomes conceivable that a neutrino of, say, charge -e* could form a bound state with a Higg's particle of charge e*. If the coupling is strong enough, the negative binding energy might reduce the composite to zero mass.

It might then be the case that QFT influences that would otherwise cause the Higgs mass to diverge are actually required to pump things up to the observed value.

Then, the SUSY partners of the familiar particles, that also might have stabilized the Higgs mass, could be dispensed with without loss.

Comment: If you google "Wess-Zumino sector", you will find a handful of papers discussing such a possibility.

Comment: Has this possibility been discussed in connection with the null results of the LHC? Then, SUSY wouldn't be dead but reinterpreted.

Comment: The main reason to expect susy at the LHC was that superpartners could naturally cancel virtual effects that would otherwise destabilize the Higgs mass. It's a different application.

Comment: It seems that one interpretation of the LHC result is that the discovery of the Higgs shows that its mass is alternatively stabilized, which would leave the sector idea and possibly relocate the SUSY business to the astronomy dept.